# Permutation with random sampling (with replacement) in linear regression in R

Tags: r, permutation, linear-regression, random

I want to permutate a linear regression (to not lose power with random sampling with replacement).

I know how to randomly sample my dataset:

```
 sampled_random <- df[sample(nrow(df), replace = TRUE),]
```

My regression is like this:

```
reg <- lm(DV ~ Iv1 + IV2  + IV3,  data = df)
```

Is there a nice built-in function to repeat this regression x times with different sample_random that I have overseen? As outcome I want the average p-values and the other averaged stuff that you get with `summary(reg)`

I am not experienced enough to write my own function that does all I want. Is there an R package that does this? Or, better, can you recommend a good (handy) one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own code.

```
res <- lapply(1:100, function(i){
    sampled_random <- df[sample(nrow(df), replace = TRUE),]
    reg <- lm(DV ~ Iv1 + IV2  + IV3,  data = sampled_random)
    return(c(summary(reg)$residuals, summary(reg)$r.squared))
})
```

Comment: Thank you Ven Yao, I was looking for something like this.